# Nginx 404 Not Found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, laravel-5, migration

I recently had a server copied over from the previous host to an AWS server. The server is Ubuntu 14.04 and the project that I am trying to run is a Laravel 5 project. I have installed nginx as the web server, here is the default file in sites available and sites enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root web/project/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have set cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0; in my php.ini file, as I was instructed to do.

There is a directory called "web" in which the project lives, and inside of the project folder lies the "public" directory.

When I try to go to the server's IP I get a 404 Not Found Error.

Any thoughts as to what may be going wrong?

Comment: What is the security group of your EC2 instance can you paste the rules

Comment: It is open for SSH, HTML and MySQL/Aurora. I was planning on tightening up the rules once it is working so that I can troubleshoot that in the future and not while I can't get it running.

Comment: Your Port is open for HTML or HTTP?

Comment: The root needs to be an absolute path like `/web/project/public`

Comment: Thank you, I ended up getting it to work by putting the absolute path all the way back to the home directory. Seems to work now, except none of the links are working, just the homepage. Oh well, one step at a time!